# ejabberd not storing unacknowledged messages to offline storage

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm running Ejabberd 15.07.33 on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I'm using the basic configuration, just added `mod_offline_post` (from `mod_interact`). I've read about dead connections problem and how to overcome it, but this post on ejabberd website (https://www.ejabberd.im/faq/tcp) says that unacknowledged messages should end up in offline storage, which is not the case in my situation. is there any special config that I should set to let this happen? I've tried to set `resend_on_timeout but didn't change anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you overcome the dead connections problem? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisR. I gave up on ejabberd long time ago and built my own messaging server, JSON over websockets. I used play framework as a websockets server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I figured out that I should enable Stream Management XEP-0198 from client side too. I'm using Smack 4.1 and I enabled it by adding these line to my code.

```
static {
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
}
```

Comment: You should mark your own answer as approved. It will help other user :)